# RankNTypes and pattern matching

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, higher-rank-types

Is there a way in haskell to erase type information/downcast to a polymorphic value ?

In the example I have a boxed type T which can contain either an Int or a Char
And I want to write a function which extract this value without knowing which type it is.

```
{#- LANGUAGE RankNTypes -#}

data T = I Int | C Char

-- This is not working because GHC cannot bind "a"
-- with specific type Int and Char at the same time. 
-- I just want a polymorphic value back ;(
getValue :: T -> (forall a. a)
getValue (I val) = val
getValue (C val) = val

-- This on the other hand works, because the function
-- is local to the pattern matching expression
onValue :: T -> (forall a. a -> a) -> T
onValue (I val) f = I $ f val 
onValue (C val) f = C $ f val
```

Is there a way to write a function that can extract this value without forcing a type at the end ?

a getValue function like the first one ?

Let me know if it is not clear enough.

## Answer

So the question was stupid as AndrewC (in the comment) and YellPika pointed out. An infinite type has no meaning.

J. Abrahamson provides an explanation for what I am looking for, so I put his answer as the solution.

P.S: I do not want to use GADT as I do not want a new type each time.

Comment: `getValue` won't be able to provide *any* a; only `Char` or `Int`

Comment: Yeah I know, but I want to lose this information. Just use them as any value

Comment: What would you want to do with a value that the compiler cannot deduce the type of? If you genuinely don't care what type the data is, just write a polymorphic function to deal with the value and run your data of type `T` through that. Polymorphic functions are how to be type agnostic.

Comment: thanks, I understand now that this is a silly question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you probably want is not to return a value `(forall a . a)` as it is wrong on several fronts. For one, you do not have *any* value but instead just one of two. For two, such a type cannot exist in a well-behaved program: it corresponds to the type of infinite loops and exceptions, e.g. bottom.

Finally, such a type allows the person who owns it to make the choice to instantiate it more concretely. Since you're giving it to the caller of your function that means that they would get to choose which of an Int or Char you had. Clearly that doesn't make sense.

Instead, what you most likely want is to make a demand of the user of your function: "you have to work regardless of what this type is".

```
foo :: (forall a . a -> r) -> (T -> r)
foo f (I i) = f i
foo f (C c) = f c
```

You'll find this function to be really similar to the following

```
bar :: r -> T -> r
bar x (I _) = x
bar x (C _) = x
```

In other words, if you force the consumer of your function to disregard *all* type information then, well, actually nothing at all remains: e.g. a constant function.

Comment: Actually, `foo` looks far less useful than `bar`, since if `f :: (forall a . a -> r)` then `f` is constant by parametricity (I think). Hence it can not discriminate between the `I` and `C` cases.

Comment: Oh, that's true! Serves me right for writing it all out on a phone. I'll amend it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `GADTs`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data T a where
    I :: Int -> T Int
    C :: Char -> T Char

getValue :: T a -> a
getValue (I i) = i
getValue (C c) = c
```

Comment: I thought about that, but I wanted to use T as a generic type (aka use it in a list) and not create a new type each time

Answer (score 3):

If you turn on `ExistentialTypes`, you can write:

```
data Anything = forall a. Anything a

getValue :: T -> Anything
getValue (I val) = Anything val
getValue (C val) = Anything val
```

However, this is pretty useless. Say we pattern match on an `Anything`:

```
doSomethingWith (Anything x) = ?
```

We don't know anything about `x` other than that it exists... (well, not even - it might be `undefined`). There's no type information, so we can't do anything with it.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me to understand that my question was stupid